# Как создать такой блок в виде кривой линии с навигацией?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть ломанная кривая, на которой расположены ссылки в виде кругов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует, как правильно создать такую навигацию?
Это нужно просто вырезать из psd линию в виде точек, сохранить в формате png, а потом сверху расположить кружки в виде ссылок, и спозиционировать ссылки абсолютно?
Подскажите, как правильно сделать это, желательно решение адаптивное.
Или это нужно делать с помощью svg?

Comment: На адаптиве можно будет убрать линии и выстроить меню в ряд по несколько штук. А так да, либо свг, либо пнг.

Answer (score 3):

Чёрные круги кликабельны ...можете проверить, иконок не было и потому они просто чёрные ..собственно так это делается

https://jsfiddle.net/v0of2cj8/  здесь можно проверить кликабельность

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 542.55688 87.708679"><style>.s0{fill:#000;}</style><g transform="translate(341.37139,-124.88531)"><path d="m-340.93452 176.80357c43.57241-21.16166 94.58049 7.06298 129.28747-14.17257 37.50011-22.94453 97.89256-41.66788 144.554379-11.19519 53.523356 34.95363 155.871501 90.75382 165.431792 39.37454 7.642669-41.0735 80.210929-29.02063 101.988259-65.41154" style="fill:none;stroke-dasharray:2.00000006, 6.00000017;stroke-width:2;stroke:#f70000"/><a xlink:role="button" target="_blank" xlink:href="http://google.com"><ellipse cx="-207.13095" cy="160.92857" rx="16.630953" ry="17.386904" class="s0"/></a><a xlink:role="button" target="_blank" xlink:href="http://yandex.ru"><ellipse ry="17.386904" rx="16.630953" cy="167.73215" cx="-41.577374" class="s0"/></a><a xlink:role="button" target="_blank" xlink:href="http://rambler.ru"><ellipse cx="96.005966" cy="194.94643" rx="16.630953" ry="17.386904" class="s0"/></a></g></svg>
```

Comment: можете рассказать, как вы это сделали? это генератор есть какой-то?

Comment: inkscape я в нём рисовал